# Create a sprite graphics from 400 graphics?

Tags: sprite, photoshop

I need to create a sprite graphic, I hope that's the right name for it, to use that with jQuery to move that graphic from position to position to make it look like a gif animation.

As I have 400 graphics (all the same size) which should become one single image later, is there a way to create that sprite automated with Photoshop CS5 or any other Software?
So that it will create that sprite image from all my 400 pics?

I was searching for such a thing now for weeks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://css-sprit.es/

This service might help you.

Also google "generate sprite"

Answer (score 1):

Some css sprite generator are already available. Just upload your images and it will automatically give u the sprite image file and css for it.

- http://spritegen.website-performance.org
- http://www.csssprites.com
- http://csssprites.org

You can use [sprite-me](http://spriteme.org/). Just bookmark the link provided in the website than open your website and run sprite-me, it will automatically show images used in the website in groups and when clicking on generate sprite, you will get sprite image and css.

Comment: http://spritegen.website-performance.org
http://www.csssprites.com  is not an option. First one allows 0.5 MB zip upload and second you have to upload files one by one. Consider 400 files.

Comment: That's exactly my problem! Each file ist around 15kb and I have 400 Files ... anything without that restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a little tutorial explaining how to create sprites. It might help you to write your own java program.

https://sites.google.com/site/javagamescorner/home/creating-sprites